# ASP MVC 2 issue - trying to display images in a for-loop in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, view, for-loop

I'm trying to display a ranking for a video game review.  The ranking is displayed by the number of gold stars out of 5.  So, if a game has a review score of 3, there should be 3 gold stars, followed by two gray/empty stars.

I have the following loops in my view to render the images:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Game.ReviewScore; ++i)
       { %>
           <img src="~/Content/Images/Review/goodscore.png" alt="" runat="server" />
    <% } %> 

<% for (int j = 0; j < (5 - Model.Game.ReviewScore); ++j)
       { %>
           <img src="~/Content/Images/Review/badscore.png" alt="" runat="server" />
    <% } %>
```

The problem is that only one `goodscore.png` image is being displayed in the loop.  Similarly, if the score allows for empty stars, only one `badscore.png` is displayed.

Looking at the rendered HTML for a game with a score of 3, I see:

```
<img src="../Content/Images/Review/goodscore.png" />
<img />
<img />
<img src="../Content/Images/Review/badscore.png" />
<img />
```

So, it looks like the math in my loops is right, it's just that the image path isn't being written into the 2nd+ iterations.  Any ideas on what's causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you need to remove the `runat="server"` inside your img tags.  This tells ASP to handle the tag.  You want the client to display the image.

Use a helper, eg: `Url.Content(...)` to insert the correct path beginning with a ~ in MVC.

Comment: Is that a pre-existing helper?

Comment: Yes, it is `Url.Content(applicationAbsolutePath);` in your view should work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx